# Invoke a Method when a Method is called

Tags: c#, .net

How can I Invoke a method in a class whenever a method in the same class is called?

Instead of doing this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private void InvokeMe() { }

    public void Method1()
    {
        this.InvokeMe();
        // some codes
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        this.InvokeMe();
        // some codes
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        this.InvokeMe();
        // some codes
    }

    // more methods
}
```

I want to automatically invoke the InvokeMe private method instead of putting it on each of the public methods in MyClass because we have too many method in that class and that class always change.

My code is in C#, Framework 4.0, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: ALthough it might be tedious to go through and put it on each method, it is likely that it's possible to have unit tests that test every method on the class and make sure they're calling the InvokeMe method. That will mean that if someone adds a method and doesn't call InvokeMe, it will cause the tests to fail, thus ensuring it gets attention.

Comment: You're right (it's really tedious), but this is a Service Class and the InvokeMe is only used for security purposes and we do not need to call it when unit testing.

Comment: Great way to push code that's getting beyond maintainable into a truly gothic abomination.  Don't do it.

Comment: I agree with Hans. "because we have too many method in that class and that class always change" => This is an indication that you need to refactor, particular if different parts or methods of the class are changing for different reasons.

Comment: @HansPassant Guess I have no choice then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be accomplished using some Aspect programming (take a look at PostSharp or one of its alternatives). Alternatively since you are using .NET 4 you *could* create a [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) implementation to act as a proxy for your class and when a method is called on it have it call the `InvokeMe` method first.

UPDATE

I've added a link to the `DynamicObject` documentation above for further reading. There's a good MSDN blog available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/10/18/on-dynamic-objects-and-dynamicobject.aspx) that discusses the relevant points.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I create a DynamicObject (and what is a DynamicObject)?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona Unfortunately AFAIK you will have to use a third party library if you want to accomplish what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Postsharp is an option but it has a button that says "Purchase" (unless you are happy with their free starter edition).

If you are looking for other, less expensive options, try for example [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) or [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/).

In some of my projects I have used Ninject exactly as you described and it was easy to use. Please be aware that interception (or Aspect-Oriented Programming) introduces a new set of concepts and it pays off to be aware of that.

Also note that just because it worked for my projects doesn't mean that it will work for your projects as well as other factors may influence your choice.